# If state contains object containing one property, should we still create a copy and then change it in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning React, and came across the term "reducer". I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  count: 0,
}
```

My question is:

Should we still create a copy and then change it in the reducer?

See my code below:

```
const counterReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREASE':
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
    case 'DECREASE':
      return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Should we still use `...state` even if we have only one property `count`?

Or, is it okay to just change the value of `count` directly? Like this: `return { count: state.count + 1 };`.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. usually, we pass `return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };` because we don't want to change the other keys of the store, but here as you have only `count` you should only use `return { count: state.count + 1 }`

Comment: You can do it directly also. But in my opinion, its good practice to spread your state and change the desired value because if you later decide to add any other key in your state, you would have to change all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not bad to keep the spread but if you're facing perf issues you can consider not using it. Since it's a good practice to conserve a solid state you maybe can externalize the concept in a function

```js
const setCount => (state, newCount) => ({
  // ...state, // If you want later spread state
  count: newCount
})

const counterReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREASE':
      return setCount(state, state.count + 1);
    case 'DECREASE':
      return setCount(state, state.count - 1);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Alternatively, if you have only one property, you maybe not need an object and use the state directly :

```js
// This way `state = 0` instead of `{ count = 0}`
const counterReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREASE':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREASE':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Looking at the redux doc : https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#splitting-reducers : there is many ways to use state. Some of them are not even relative to `state` but comes from `action` directly. In all the cases, if you keep the reducer safe and well documented (if it's not the general usecases / standard), you're good :)

PS: I recommand you to read the native `react` useReducer fonctionnality : https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer since it cover the main useCases and can replace easly the redux framework.